# Function's graph sketch

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

$f(x) = x+9$

$g(x) = 2x-3$

I need to draw the sketch of $\min(f,g)$ and $\max(f,g)$.  I tried:

http://sketchtoy.com/62375984

The yellow is the min and the blue is max. The lines should be straight, sorry. So, am I right?
Thanks.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Confirmed, correct=)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)